# Reduce session size legth

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I had a programmer develop one of the framework adn he's currently away for a week. Basically he used CodeIgniter to develop a framework.

Whenever I access the dev environment, it stores a lengthy cookie. Where should I look at to reduce the session size?

> Set-Cookie:
>   mysite_session=AjgDOFk%2FXDoPelgiAm8ENVs%2BUjlQIwNzUDMAIFB3BWoFawFpAQpROFRrCygHbl1yAzcONAdiU2lUIwFkVT0DNgRgAzEHagRgDDVWMwg%2BUTcCbQMyWTpcYg9iWGACMwRmWzlSYlA4AzRQZgAyUDQFYAU9AWEBNFE1VDoLKAduXXIDNw42B2BTaVQjATlVdANfBGMDNAc3BHAMaFYjCC9RcwJiA3FZMVwxDzNYawJ3BDVbNlI7UC8DOVBlAH1QNQUzBSoBMgFjUXNUNAt5B29dMAM9Dj0HclMmVHIBNVV2A18EYwM3BzYEbAx5VnIIZ1EiAmMDNlk%2BXDoPI1gGAjAEZlsjUnBQbwNpUDAANVBhBXEFKwE2AXtRYVQhCzkHYl0hAyUOLAc4UydUdQEgVT4DLwQtAycHNgRgDCBWIwgyUTgCPwNkWW5ccg8vWD8CMARwWyFSKlAjAztQJQBpUDUFMAU%2BASUBOVEwVHwLfgcKXWADbg5zBzlTJVRoASRVfQMiBDkDOQdpBDMMPlZjCGhRYgJtAzBZP1w0DzVYagIo;
>   path=/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of interest why is this a concern?

You can look in

application/config/config.php

search for $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'], if it is set to TRUE, try setting it to FALSE. This will reduce the size of the cookie but obviously as the name suggests it will not encrypt session data.

Comment: I thought the wait time from the server was due to this, as it turns out it was a mysql misconfiguration. I turned on the db cache and also optimized the SQL and it works much better now.

The thing is session size had nothing to do with it, it was my lack of knowledge on this.

Comment: Good stuff, glad you sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure but try to look for this :

```
ini_set('session.hash_function', 'sha512');
ini_set('session.hash_function', '1');
ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', '6');
```

This can and may reduce the length, also the security encryption. [See for more infos](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)